# navigate to a local target

Tags: ros, local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ros-users,
I'm searching something to navigate toward an ar_tag. In particular, I would like to take information only regarding to the tag, avoiding reference to a global frame.
I'm (still..) working on ros fuerte.
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187231/navigate-to-a-local-target/) by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-07-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, take a look at https://github.com/yujinrobot/yujin_ocs/tree/indigo. The three packages named yocs_ar_ .... could be what you are looking for. But that's indigo code, so you will need to adapt it.

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2014-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1